# How to display the number of kubernetes pods restarted during a time period?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-pod

I have kubernetes clusters with prometheus and grafana for monitoring and I am trying to build a dashboard panel that would display the number of pods that have been restarted in the period I am looking at.

Atm I have this query that fills a vector with 1 if the pod's creation time is  in the range (meaning it has been restarted during this period) and -1 otherwise.

`-sgn((time() - kube_pod_created{cluster="$cluster"}) - $__range_s)`

[what this looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8BjL.png)

Is there a way to count the number of positive values in this vector and display it? Like in this example just have a box with red 1 inside.
Or maybe there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying.

Comment: By definition, pods themselves do not "restart", but their containers do.

Are you trying to count pods recreation or container restarts?

Comment: I trying to count pods recreation, like when use `kubectl get pods` and see pods' age.
I came up with this solution : `count($__range_s - (time() - kube_pod_created{cluster="$cluster"}) > 0)`.
I'll be glad to hear about another solution because this one seems somewhat convoluted but at least does the work.

Answer (score 8):

To display the Pod Restarts we have different Prometheus metrics

`kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total`. This is the counter metrics and this will record the container restarts.

To calculate the restarts:

- If you want to see all pods then,
  `sum(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="My-Namespace"}[5m])) by(pod)`
- or If you want Particular Pod then use,
  `sum(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="My-Namespace", pod="My-Pod"}[5m]))`
- or to show by container wise use
  `sum(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="My-Namespace", pod="My-Pod"}[5m])) by(container)`